# Can I share my usb keyboard between two computers

Tags: usb, keyboard, switch

I love my Filco keyboard, I use it as primary keyboard for my Lenovo thinkpad all time. Now Im moving into the mac world and wonder:

is it possible to split my USB keyboard between two USB ports, ie one at my lenovo and one at my new iMac.

I was thinking that maybe there exists some kind of box with a switch to decide which port should receive the input, or preferable it would be possible to switch between the two via a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Search your favorite vendor for `KVM`s.

Comment: You could do this in software easily with something like synergy, if you weren't tied into a hardware solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used one that just does USB (USB switch) but I have used a few [KVM switches<sup>*****</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) and most of them allowed me to switch with a keyboard command.

<sup>*****</sup> <sub>You don't have to connect monitor and mouse to the KVM if you don't want to.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you need hardware to make it happen, SIIG makes a [usb 2.0 switch](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812191011) There are other manufacturers, just posted this one as an example of what to look for.